# Preg_Match_All: two values in a pattern

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-match-all

I have custom tags `[tag val=100][/tag]`. How do I get `val` and whatever goes between the tags?

ex:

```
[tag val=100]apple[/tag]
```

value1 = 100
value2 = apple

edit: what if I had multiple items inside the tag
ex:

```
[tag val=100 id=3]
```

Comment: Are the tags nestable, e.g., `[tag val=100]fruits: [tag2]apples[/tag2] and pears[/tag]`?

Comment: Regarding your edit: Is the selection of available attributes inside fixed? Or do you want to check anything possible?

Comment: if you are asking for a *regular* expression, then you should be clear about the *regularity*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string like that in your question, you can use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`:

```
$str = "[tag val=100]apple[/tag]";

preg_match("/\[.+? val=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/.+?\]/", $str, $matches);

$value = $matches[1];    // "100"
$content = $matches[2];  // "apple"
```

**Update:** I see you might have multiple attributes in each element. In that case, this should work:

```
// captures all attributes in one group, and the value in another group
preg_match("/\[.+?((?:\s+.+?=.+?)+)\](.+?)\[\/.+?\]/", $str, $matches);

$attributes = $matches[1];
$content = $matches[2];

// split attributes into multiple "key=value" pairs
$param_pairs = preg_split("/\s+/", $attributes, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
// create dictionary of attributes
$params = array();
foreach ($param_pairs as $pair) {
    $key_value = explode("=", $pair);
    $params[$key_value[0]] = $key_value[1];
}
```

Comment: You could tweak the RE slightly to restrict the characters that can be used for attribute names and values. I've used `.+?` but you could change that to `[A-Za-z]+?` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a regular expression for it:

```
'#\[tag val=([0-9]+)\]([a-zA-Z]+)\[\/tag])#'
```

Val would be a number and your 'apple' can be one or more occurences of alphabetic characters. Replace `[a-zA-Z]+` by `.+?` if you want to match more characters.